# Error: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, angular, testing, chai

I want to test a property of an HTML eemnet using Chai like this:

```html
const chai = require('chai');
const expect  = chai.expect;
expect(document.getElementById('ref_button')).to.have.attr('disabled');
```

Wen I put this line fr chai-dom  `chai.use(require('chai-dom'))`
it thrws the error:

```html
Unhandled rejection ReferenceError: document is not defined at     
C:\Users\67563478\new_workspace\onconsup\node_modules\chai-dom\chai-dom.js:69:53 at Object.exports.use
(C:\Users\67563478\new_workspace\onconsup\node_modules\chai\lib\chai.js:39:5)
```

And the line inside chai-dom whoc thros the error is this one:

```
NODE_LIST_STRING = Object.prototype.toString.call(document.childNodes),
```

i REMOVED THIS LINE AND THAT ERROR IS NOT ANYMORE. Now the error is `document is not defined` for the line of document.getElementById.
What should I do? Maybe is the library chai-dom deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

`document` is a browser-specific global variable that is not defined in Node.js environment so when you refer to a `document` chai has no idea what it is and how to find it.

Moreover, there is (probably - as you didn't show how HTML file is wired to chai) no connection between a button and a test for it.

To solve a problem you can have a look at JSDOM (https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) that implements WHATWG DOM and HTML standards. Alternatively, you may choose to use headless browser such as headless chrome (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer).

Picking an option to go with requires a little bit more knowledge about your use case.

Comment: Can't I use something else to reference the HTMl elemenets instead of docuement?

Comment: And about the connection betwen teh button and teh test, what kind of connection can I make? I protractor in my previous steps I use element(by.css("*[id='buttton']")).sendKeys or example and it works wthout making any conenction